# after the matched cell, search in the succeeding rows for a value with specific string and return the value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, find

May I ask how to search in the succeeding rows after matched cell, for a value with specific string and return the value along with the first matched cell

here is the sample of my code

```
Sub test()
x = 1
For Line = 2 To Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If InStr(1, Range("B" & Line), "Main") <> 0 And InStr(1, Range("B" & Line), "Sub") <> 0 Then
    x = x + 1
    Range("F" & x) = Range("B" & Line)
    Range("E" & x) = Range("A" & Line)
    Range("G" & x) = Range("B" & Line).
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

I'm having problem returning the value at column G that is related to the match at column E and F

[image]

here is the sample of what should the code must do

Comment: You wrote : _I'm having problem returning the value at column G that is related to the **match at column E and F**_. Just curious, in the image, is column E to G the expected result after running the sub ? Or in column E and F is the "query" where the expected result is just in column G? I ask because your code is not comparing what is in column E nth row to column A and also not comparing what is in column F nth row to column B. Your code is just "extracting" if the looped cell offset 0,1 contains the word "Main" and "Sub". Is not comparing "Main1.Sub" or "Main2.Sub" etc. Please CMIIW.

Comment: the expected result are reflected in columns E,F,G...and yes just extracting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub SubDataExtraction()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim DblIndex As Double
    Dim VarResult() As Variant
    Dim RngResult As Range
    Dim RngCell As Range
    Dim RngData As Range
    Dim StrSearchWord01 As String
    Dim StrSearchWord02 As String
    Dim StrSearchWord03 As String
    
    'Settings.
    Set RngData = Range(Range("B2"), Range("B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
    Set RngResult = Range("E2")
    StrSearchWord01 = "Main"
    StrSearchWord02 = "Sub"
    StrSearchWord03 = "animal"
    ReDim VarResult(1 To RngData.Rows.Count, 1 To 3)
    
    'Covering each cell of RngData.
    For Each RngCell In RngData
        
        'Checking if RngCell contains both StrSearchWord01 and StrSearchWord02.
        If InStr(1, RngCell.Value2, StrSearchWord01) <> 0 And InStr(1, RngCell.Value2, StrSearchWord02) <> 0 Then
            
            'Setting DblIndex for the next row of results.
            DblIndex = DblIndex + 1
            
            'Reporting the values in VarResult (column 1 and 2).
            VarResult(DblIndex, 1) = RngCell.Offset(0, -1).Value2
            VarResult(DblIndex, 2) = RngCell.Value2
            
        End If
        
        'Checking if RngCell contains StrSearchWord03 and if VarResult hasn't already a value in the first and third column.
        If InStr(1, RngCell.Value2, StrSearchWord03) <> 0 And _
           VarResult(Excel.WorksheetFunction.Max(DblIndex, 1), 3) = "" And _
           VarResult(Excel.WorksheetFunction.Max(DblIndex, 1), 1) <> "" _
           Then
            
            'Reporting the value in VarResult (column 3).
            VarResult(DblIndex, 3) = RngCell.Value2
            
        End If
        
    Next
    
    'Reporting the result in RngResult properly expanded.
    RngResult.Resize(DblIndex, UBound(VarResult, 2)).Value2 = VarResult
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much for this...i will try to expand the search words using this code

Comment: Hi I encountered that if there's a "animal:" before the first "Main" to be found, the code will encounter an error, highlighting the If statement related to column 3. Is there any way  to edit the code that will search succeeding only row if "Main" and "Sub" is first to be found? i try Do While statement but i am at lost

Comment: Sure, much likely animal is not re-written if it had been found already. I'll edit the code.

Comment: Done. Now the third column value will be filled only if the first one has been already (and of course if the third column hasn't been already filled and therefore the word has been found for the first time in the current Main**N**.Sub sub-segment).

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test2()

Dim x As Long, Line As Long, SubLine As Long

x = 1
For Line = 2 To Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If InStr(1, Range("B" & Line), "Main") <> 0 And InStr(1, Range("B" & Line), "Sub") <> 0 Then
        
        SubLine = Line
        Do Until Range("A" & SubLine) <> Range("A" & SubLine + 1)
            SubLine = SubLine + 1
        Loop
        
        x = x + 1
        Range("E" & x) = Range("A" & Line)
        Range("F" & x) = Range("B" & Line)
        Range("G" & x) = Range("B" & SubLine)
    End If
Next

End Sub
```